# How to make a larger buffer from existing UnsafeMutablePointer in swift

Tags: swift

I'm trying to avoid using malloc, realloc and NSMutableData to read data into a buffer using UnsafeMutablePointer. Once the buffer fills up, how do I increase it's size to make room for more data?

```
let oldBufferSize = 10
let oldBuffer = UnsafeMutablePointer<Int>.alloc(oldBufferSize)
for i in 0..< oldBufferSize {
    oldBuffer[i] = Int(arc4random())
}

//Is this the right way? Is there another way to do it?
let newBufferSize = oldBufferSize + 15
let newBuffer = UnsafeMutablePointer<Int>.alloc(newBufferSize)
newBuffer.initializeFrom(oldBuffer, count: oldBufferSize)
oldBuffer.dealloc()


for i in oldBufferSize..< newBufferSize {
    newBuffer[i] = Int(arc4random())
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `realloc`, which will allocate memory for a new buffer, and copy the contents of the old buffer if needed. `realloc` will keep the same memory address if possible; i.e. if there's enough free memory next to the old buffer to expand it to the size of the new buffer:

```
let newBuffer =  UnsafeMutablePointer<Int>(realloc(buffer, newBufferSize * sizeof(Int)))
```

**Note 1.** `realloc` works on `Void` pointers, so the actual size of the new buffer must be multiplied by the size of the type you're working with.

**Note 2.** You need to call `dealloc` on the old buffer only if the memory address of the new buffer differs from the one of the old one.

**Note 3.** You can also use `NSMutableData` if you want to write to an expanding buffer.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry, I failed to mention that I was trying to avoid malloc and realloc if possible. Do you know an alternative?

Comment: You can use `NSMutableData` if you want to write to an expanding buffer. But you should update your question as it's not clearly what you intend to achieve.